# Ruby - Watir - Get HTML with interpreted js

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, watir

After doing this on my ruby file :

```
 browser = Watir::Browser.new
 browser.goto 'anyWebsite.com'

 puts browser.html > "~/index.html"
```

I get an HTML code but with non-interpreted JavaScript.
For example, I get things like that :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My question is, how can I get the HTML **after js interpretation** ?

Comment: That's not non-interpreted JavaScript. That's simply a reference. The JavaScript is fetched and interpreted by the browser.

Comment: OK, thks for this precision (I'm a beginner in Web development). So : how can I get the resulting HTML after the browser fetched and interpreted it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `html` method, you are getting the current DOM - ie the HTML after javascript interpretation.

For example, take a simple html page that includes javascript to add a button:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
      document.body.appendChild(btn);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you go to the page and get the browser html, you can see that it also includes the button added by the javascript (see the end of the second last line) - ie the html is after javascript has been interpreted:

```
browser.html
#=> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body>
#=>     <script>
#=>       var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
#=>       document.body.appendChild(btn);
#=>     </script><button></button>
#=> </body></html>
```

Similarly, you can see that the html of a specific element is also after interpretation:

```
browser.body.html
#=> <body>
#=>     <script>
#=>       var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
#=>       document.body.appendChild(btn);
#=>     </script><button></button>
#=> </body>
```

Comment: I understand more so my question has changed :
Can I do the same result as the part in the <script> with <button> ?
Because my goal is to make a Website without any script from a Website already existing.
And I was hopping not to have to learn HTML but it seems that I have to.
Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: You do not need any scripts if your page is static. But I am not sure I am really understanding your question given that you are now talking about creating a page rather than Watir, which tests pages. I would suggest you give a more concrete example of exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: For example, I need to take a Website like : https://stackoverflow.com/
And to make exactly the same but totally static.
So I was trying to get the html from each pages (using watir) and that's all. But, because of the javascript like :
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
I don't have the same result at all if I open the html file in a browser (without internet connection).

But if I get the code in jquery.min.js and put it into my html file, will I have the same result ?

Comment: You would get the same results to a point. For example, all the jQuery UI widgets would render correctly. However, data that is being asynchronously retrieved (eg some autocompletes), will not be there.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for all your explanations.
For the asynchronously data, I will find a solution (in the worse case, I will re-generate the HTML using script).